# Using XPath to find all attributes in a particular namespace

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'd like to see if any attributes exist in my XML document in a particular namespace. I thought that `//@ns:*` would do it, but this finds attributes any all namespaces:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri' # Ruby library using libxml2
doc = Nokogiri.XML '<r xmlns:f="f" xmlns:b="b"><e a="no" f:a="yes" b:a="no"/></r>'
p doc.xpath('//@f:*')
#=> [
#=>   #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fca52c02888 name="a" value="no">,
#=>   #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fca52c02874 name="a" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fca52c02450 prefix="f" href="foo"> value="yes">,
#=>   #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fca52c02860 name="a" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fca52c08008 prefix="b" href="bar"> value="no">
#=> ]
```

This same approach works when looking only for elements that match a namespace:

```ruby
doc = Nokogiri.XML '<r xmlns:f="foo" xmlns:b="bar"><e/><f:e/><b:e/></r>'
p doc.xpath('//f:*')
#=> [
#=>   #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fca524755ac name="e" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fca5247555c prefix="f" href="foo">>
#=> ]
```

---

FWIW, the non-XPath workaround in Ruby is:

```ruby
p doc.xpath('//@*').select{ |a| a.namespace && a.namespace.prefix=='f' }
#=> [
#=>   #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fca52c02874 name="a" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fca52c02450 prefix="f" href="foo"> value="yes">,
#=> ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping there's a more elegant answer, but this works:

```ruby
doc.xpath('//@*[namespace-uri()="uri-for-the-namespace-not-the-prefix"]')
#=> [
#=>   #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fca5215e418 name="a" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fca5215dff4 prefix="f" href="foo"> value="yes">
#=> ]
```